# Как построить архитектуру сайта .Сайт будет предназначен для каждого региона

Tags: php, веб-программирование, laravel, архитектура

Для каждого региона создавать свой сайт с по доменом или как ?
Что бы поисковики выдавали сразу информацию для клиента по его региона.
Пишу сайт на php laravel.

Comment: либо поддомены, либо часть url

Answer (score 1):

Обычно для таких задач используют либо поддомены, либо подпапки вида /lipetks/. Чтобы поисковики выдавали пользователю данные из его регионов - данные должны быть статически доступны. Желательно избегать передачи региональных параметров через GET.

Поддомен или папка будут лучше регионально индексироваться и двигаться, нежели сайт с выбором региона на JS и изменением данных через GET.

Стоит ли разделять базы данных для каждого региона зависит от объёма данных и критичности различий между головной версией сайта и региональными вариантами.

Как правило отдельное хранение данных для каждого региона легче и удобнее разрабатывать, однако тяжелее администрировать из одного центра. Если же есть возможность спихнуть администрирование на руководителей филиалов регионов - то разделение будет идеальным решением т.к. не придется писать ограничение прав доступа к другим регионам из админки.

Для определения региона и перенаправления пользователя используют базу ip

Вот хорошая глобальная база:
https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-services-and-databases

Вот база от sypex:
https://sypexgeo.net/ru/docs/

К обеим базам есть развернутая документация так что проблем с внедрением быть не должно.